# AWS S3 Bucket counts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have tried to run these commands:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket --profile key --output json --query "[length(Contents[])]"
```

and

```
aws s3 --profile=key ls s3://bucket/ --recursive --summarize
```

but what I'm curious about is that some of the objects have been marked for deletion. Do these commands count the objects marked for deletion or are they excluded?

Comment: What do you mean by "some of the objects have been marked for deletion"? If versioning is enabled on an Amazon S3 bucket, deleted objects are retained but a **delete marker** is added so that they _appear_ to be deleted but previous versions of the object are still available. However, there is no concept of "marked for deletion" in Amazon S3.

Comment: So, that being the case, will list-objects or ls count the previous version or will it be excluded?

Comment: I think they will show a count of objects, without including multiple versions of an object. What did you mean by "some of the objects have been marked for deletion"?

Answer (score 0):

commands shared here will list objects/files given in a specified path. these commands will not display any of the deleted objects. for details refer [S3 ls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)